# Why auto mounting sshfs using autofs fails?

Tags: ssh, fedora, autofs

I'm desperetely trying to auto mount my distant folder using autofs & sshfs, but I can't make it work. (I'm under Fedora 16)

This works :

```
sshfs cx42net@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/my/data /home/cx42net/data-distant -o uid=1000 -o gid=1000
```

So I defined a RSA key to use with ssh, tried a `ssh` connect, it worked without asking my password. Then I tried again the previous `sshfs` command, and it worked well (yay!)

So now, I want to use `autofs`, and that's where the problem starts :

Content of my /etc/auto.master file :

```
#
# Sample auto.master file
# This is an automounter map and it has the following format
# key [ -mount-options-separated-by-comma ] location
# For details of the format look at autofs(5).
#
/misc   /etc/auto.misc
#
# NOTE: mounts done from a hosts map will be mounted with the
#       "nosuid" and "nodev" options unless the "suid" and "dev"
#       options are explicitly given.
#
/net    -hosts
#
# Include /etc/auto.master.d/*.autofs
#
+dir:/etc/auto.master.d
#
# Include central master map if it can be found using
# nsswitch sources.
#
# Note that if there are entries for /net or /misc (as

# above) in the included master map any keys that are the
# same will not be seen as the first read key seen takes
# precedence.
#
+auto.master

/net    /etc/auto.sshfs    uid=1000,gid=1000,--timeout=30,--ghost
```

(1000:1000) is my local user uid/gid, not the distant (the SSH folder I'm trying to get)

My /etc/auto.sshfs :

```
data-distant    -fstype=fuse,port=22,rw,allow_other    :sshfs\#cx42net@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\:/mnt/data/dev
```

When I start autofs, here's what I've got in the `/var/log/messages` :

```
Oct 28 23:59:30 pc-maison autofs[3318]: Starting automount: [  OK  ]
```

So everything seems fine.

But I sometimes got this kind of messages:

```
Oct 28 23:41:01 pc-maison automount[2453]: create_udp_client: hostname lookup failed: Name or service not known
Oct 28 23:41:01 pc-maison automount[2453]: create_tcp_client: hostname lookup failed: Name or service not known
Oct 28 23:41:01 pc-maison automount[2453]: lookup_mount: exports lookup failed for data-distant
```

The folder `/net/data-distant` have rights of my user "cx42net" (1000:1000)

What am I missing to make this works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short:

Check that your sshfs command works with root user.

## Longer:

Check that root user has ssh identity keys setup.
Mounting of sshfs through autofs uses root user for the actual mount.

This is still meant only for desktop or laptop users with a single user using these mounts!

## auto.master line

note! use your own uid and gid and specify your prefered mount point
I use /auto/mehtod/address

```
/auto/sshfs /etc/auto.sshfs uid=1000,gid=1000,--timeout=60,--ghost
```

## auto.sshfs this is a bit more generic than just one mount

```
#!/bin/bash

# Shell script that acccepts one argument, namely userid@server
# env >> /tmp/env_check
# whoami >> /tmp/env_check

key=$1
USER='your_local_user_used_for_ssh_identity_file'
REMOTEDEFAULT='default_to_this_user_otherwise_root'
key=${key//[: #]/}

# add user
[[ ! "$key" =~ "@" ]] && key="${REMOTEDEFAULT}@${key}"

case $key in
   ${REMOTEDEFAULT}@.Trash*)
      exit 1;;
   *)
      (
      echo "-fstype=fuse,idmap=user,rw,nodev,nonempty,transform_symlinks,noatime,allow_other,IdentityFile=/home/${USER}/.ssh/id_dsa,max_read=65536\\"
      echo -e "\t /uhome :sshfs\#$key\:\\"
      echo -e "\t /tmp :sshfs\#$key\:\/tmp\/\\"
      echo -e "\t /rootfs :sshfs\#$key\:\/")
esac

## this is a bit more complex. It creates subfolders to autofs-mount/remotename
## /uhome  = your remote homedirectory
## /rootfs = remote root '/'
## /tmp    = remote tmp # same as /roots/tmp
```

then link to folder you want to access
ln -s /auto/sshfs/userid@my.remote.example.com/uhome/ remote-home